io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
The above error message is shown while I run my test case. Unable to proceed. Can anyone help ?
stepDefinition:-
    WebDriver driver;
@Given("^Open chrome and start application$")
public void Open_chrome_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("URL");
}

@When("^I enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_enter_valid_username_and_valid_password(String uname, String pass) throws Throwable {
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(uname);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pass);
}

@Then("^user should be able to login successfully$")
public void user_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Login']")).click();
}

testRunner:-
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "features", glue ="stepDefinition")
public class TestRunner
{
}
stepDefinition:-
    WebDriver driver;
@Given("^Open chrome and start application$")
public void Open_chrome_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
    
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("URL");
}

@When("^I enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_enter_valid_username_and_valid_password(String uname, String pass) throws Throwable {
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(uname);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pass);
}

@Then("^user should be able to login successfully$")
public void user_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Login']")).click();
}

testRunner:-
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "features", glue ="stepDefinition")
public class TestRunner
{
}
I was expecting to compile successfully & was expecting to open my browser and complete my test case.

Did you read the Java doc for glue?

Nop. But I don't see any issue with glue specified in my code. @m-p-korstanje do you see any issue in code ?

Read it. Looks like you're using the class name, not the package name. If not, please share a more complete example of your problem. You'll want to make a proper MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
